# Identify rows of one numpy array that gave rise to another numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I think I'm missing something obvious.  Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0,  2,  0,  5,  4,  6,  2,  4],
              [ 3,  4,  0,  1,  0,  7,  4,  6],
              [ 2,  6,  3,  5,  2,  5,  5,  8],
              [ 0,  1,  0,  8,  0,  5,  8, 10],
              [ 7,  9,  2,  7,  0,  6,  7,  2],
              [ 0,  1,  4,  9,  0,  7,  9,  9],
              [ 0,  6,  7,  5,  6,  2,  4, 13],
              [ 0,  1,  1,  4,  1,  3,  2,  3]]


# isolate columns 2,3,6,7
mask = [False,False, True, True,False,False, True, True]             
b = a[:,mask]

# determine rows of b having unique elements
s = np.sort(b, axis=1)
c = b[~(s[:,:-1] == s[:,1:]).any(1)]
```

`c` looks like:

```
c = [[ 0,  5,  2,  4],
     [ 0,  1,  4,  6],
     [ 7,  5,  4, 13],
     [ 1,  4,  2,  3]]
```

**QUESTION:** How do I 'recover' the rows of `a` that gave rise to the rows of `c`?
The output should be like:

```
d = [[ 0,  2,  0,  5,  4,  6,  2,  4],
     [ 3,  4,  0,  1,  0,  7,  4,  6],
     [ 0,  6,  7,  5,  6,  2,  4, 13],
     [ 0,  1,  1,  4,  1,  3,  2,  3]]
```

Comment: Can you not do `a[~(s[:,:-1] == s[:,1:]).any(1)]`?

Comment: Of course Thank you.